# Distribute array row data to make multiple new rows

Tags: php, arrays

I have below the data

```
[
    {
        "price_in_dollar": 1000,
        "price_in_euro": 1000,
        "price_in_pound": 1000,
        "price_in_rupee": 1000,
        "toy_id": 1,
        "toy_name": "Truck"
    },
    {
        "price_in_dollar": 1000,
        "price_in_euro": 1000,
        "price_in_pound": 1000,
        "price_in_rupee": 1000,
        "toy_id": 2,
        "toy_name": "Bicycle"
    }
]
```

I want to create a new array from above as below

```
[
    {
        "toy": "Truck",
        "toy_id": 1,
        "rate": 1000,
        "slug": "price_in_dollar",
    },
    {
        "toy": "Truck",
        "toy_id": 1,
        "rate": 1000,
        "slug": "price_in_euro",
    },
    ...
    {
        "toy": "Bicycle",
        "toy_id": 2,
        "rate": 1000,
        "slug": "price_in_dollar",
    },
    {
        "toy": "Bicycle",
        "toy_id": 2,
        "rate": 1000,
        "slug": "price_in_euro",
    },
    ...

]
```

I have tried the below code

```
foreach($data as $r) {
    foreach($r as $key => $value) {

        if ($key === 'toy_name') {
            $cars['toy'] =  $value ;
        }
        else if ($key === 'toy_id') {
            $cars['toy_id'] =  $value;
        }
        else {
            $cars['slug'] =  $key ;
            $cars['rate'] =  $value;
        }
    }
}
```

But it only has one set of data, how can I append all data? Or any improved code to solve this?

Comment: You want to create an array of arrays. Like so `$cars[] = ['toy' => ... , 'slug' => ...];` for every record of your original data

Comment: Yes. New array named car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code was actually replacing a `key => value` pair data, not pushing a data into `$cars`, you can fix it like this:

```php
$cars = [];
foreach($data as $r) {
    $singleCar = [
        "toy_id" => $r['toy_id'],
        "toy" => $r['toy_name'],
    ];
    
    foreach($r as $key => $val){
        if($key != 'toy_id' && $key != 'toy_name') {
            $singleCar['rate'] = $val;
            $singleCar['slug'] = $key;
            
            $cars[] = $singleCar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that this will loop everything since what I understand from your code can be described as "`toy_id` and `toy_name` are exceptions"

Comment: Tnx..........:)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below is working fine:

```
$data= [
    [
        "price_in_dollar" => 1000,
        "price_in_euro" => 1000,
        "price_in_pound" => 1000,
        "price_in_rupee" => 1000,
        "toy_id" => 1,
        "toy_name" => "Truck"
    ],
    [
        "price_in_dollar" => 1000,
        "price_in_euro" => 1000,
        "price_in_pound" => 1000,
        "price_in_rupee" => 1000,
        "toy_id" => 2,
        "toy_name" => "Bicycle"
    ]
];

$cnt = 0;

foreach($data as $r) {
    foreach($r as $key => $value) {

        if ($key === 'toy_name') {
            $cars[$cnt]['toy'] =  $value ;
        }
        else if ($key === 'toy_id') {
            $cars[$cnt]['toy_id'] =  $value;
        }
        else {
            $cars[$cnt]['slug'] =  $key ;
            $cars[$cnt]['rate'] =  $value;
        }
    }
    
    $cnt++;
}

// display result
print_r($cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
foreach($data as $r) {
foreach($r as $key => $value) {

    if ($key === 'toy_name') {
        $cars[]['toy'] =  $value ;
    }
    else if ($key === 'toy_id') {
        $cars[]['toy_id'] =  $value;
    }
    else {
        $cars[]['slug'] =  $key ;
        $cars[]['rate'] =  $value;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am rather confident that this unexplained answer does not work as required.  Those first level `[]` braces will be  creating new indexes each time and not grouping the related data.  Please prove me wrong by editing your question to including a working demo link.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop for the different currencies and use some php array functions

```php
$currencies = ['price_in_dollar', 'price_in_euro', 'price_in_pound', 'price_in_rupee'];

$data= [
    ...
];
$newData = [];
foreach($currencies as $currency) {
    $newData = array_merge(
        $newData, 
        array_map(function ($item) use ($currency) {
            return [
                "toy" => $item['toy_name'],
                "toy_id" => $item['toy_id'],
                "rate" => $item[$currency],
                "slug" => $currency,
            ];
        }, $data)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate each row, isolate the repeatable elements, then removed them from the row, then iterate the remaining elements and push the new desired associative rows into the result array.

The `unset()` call will not actually affect the original input array because the forearch is *actually* iterating a "copy" of the input array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/I2LFs))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    ['toy_id' => $id, 'toy_name' => $name] = $row;
    unset($row['toy_id'], $row['toy_name']);
    foreach ($row as $slug => $rate) {
        $result[] = compact(['id', 'name', 'slug', 'rate']);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```